# Why is everyone trying to ram me?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

So I was trying to steal a muscle car during one of the side-missions available through Saintsbook, but while driving the car back to the chop shop something rather peculiar happened. Each and every car on the road veered into my path just as I was about to pass it, making it amazingly difficult for me to reach my destination.

I've never seen this happen before, and I was wondering what is it that causes this behavior. I'd certainly like to avoid triggering this in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually when you're running a Vehicle Theft side mission, as soon as you get the target car, the cops are going to chase you.

Other drivers on the road react to police cars in unpredictable fashion - the most common thing they will do is attempt to "pull over" when police cars are approaching.

Unfortunately, the logic for "pull over" isn't always intelligent.  They'll often pull over *in front of you* as opposed to pulling over to get out of the way.

There's not much of a way to get around this sadly.  You just have to drive fast so that you pass them before they have time to react, and pass with as much lateral distance between you and the other cars as possible.  The "Nitrous on every car" upgrade can be useful here as well.

As a side note, they will react the same way if you're driving a vehicle with sirens and turn them on.  Often times the unpredictability of this yields so many issues that it's not worth using the sirens in these vehicles at all.

Comment: I had a lot of fun with a fully upgraded police car, and generally, I found that driving in the left lane on the highway with sirens is generally good. But if they don't get out of the way, my car blows their car up somehow.

Comment: @Unionhawk, yeah, oddly enough driving down the middle of the street going the wrong way is actually a fairly safe way to travel...  go figure!

Comment: This is a frequent annoyance of mine in the GTA series, and there as well I usually found it easier to drive on the wrong side of the street.

Comment: I suspected this had something to do with the police. Thanks!

Comment: Drive in the left lane if there's two lanes.